# Why "owing to" meaning has been "because of"?

Tags: word-meaning

> In dictionary "Owe" meaning has been defined as "to feel the need or
>   obligation to do, give, etc"

I haven't understood that why "Owing to" meaning has been "because of" but owe meaning is "to feel the need or obligation to do, give, etc"

Please anyone teaches me.
(addedly, Many Asian students haven't well understood that.)

Comment: I don't know if it's meaningful to ask "why" a word means something in a language.  It just does.  It's more meaningful to ask *how* to use it, or *how* to tell one meaning from another meaning (if possible).

Comment: @Andrew 'Owing to' meaning is just 'because of'? We don't explain that how made ?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what answer you want.  "Owing to their generosity I was able to buy a new car" is a sentence in English where "owing" means "due to".  If you're asking *why* it means that when it also means "obligation" or "debt" ... well, welcome to English.  Words in English can have many different meanings depending on how they are used.

Comment: @SIS Can you tell us what English language dictionary you are using? The verb _owe_ has many uses and meanings. Most dictionaries include examples of each use, which will help you understand the differences between the meanings.

Comment: @P. E. Dant I am using "Collins Dictionary".  Could you recommend one for me ?

Comment: Collins is fine, but you might try [**The Oxford Learner's Dictionaries**](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/) and, to link to many dictionaries on a single page, use the [**Onelook**](http://onelook.com) site.

Comment: At the Oxford site, you can look up [**"owing to"**](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/owing-to?q=owing+to) and [**"owing"**](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/owing?q=owing) in the search field. The verb [**"owe"**](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/owe?q=owe) has its own listing. The learner's dictionary is a good dictionary to start with.

Answer (score 0):

You ask why the meaning of "**owing to**" is equal to the meaning of "**because of**".

Well, almost in any language there are many ways to express the same things and all of them are correct and they are just a subject of choice, it is to say that you can choice the way that you want to express. Some of the ways are associated with such [register (sociolinguistics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_(sociolinguistics)) and some of them are associated with different register. But in some of the cases, you can even find some choices in the same register.

In addition, we can find different way to express the same things due to influences of different languages. As you know historically when some nations meet together they can develop a larger language by sharing words. An excellent example is USA which historically brought people from different Europe countries with different languages. This way is called [Loanword](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loanword).

Then when we are going to talk about the specific phrase "**owing to**", let's analyze it by observation of the word "owing" which means "**have an obligation to...**", can easily be metaphorically be in the meaning of "because of". It makes sense that in one point in the history time some of people used this metaphor  and then gradually it inserted the language. It could be that there are more explaination for this specific case, but I just offered to you examples of assumptions.